# Xml PHP Get attributes and its children value

Tags: php, xml, children

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<lessons>
    <lesson level="1" course="2">
                 <name type="Dog" category="Animals">Dog name</name>
          </lesson>
</lessons>
```

I want to get the values saved like this:

```
$type = "Dog";
$category = "Animals";
$name = "dog name";
```

This is what I've done:

```
    foreach($xml->name as $name){
        $type = $name['type'];
        $category = $name['category'];

        echo "Type: $type Category: $category<br>";
        // AND TO get the text, haven't figuered it out yet.. <name ..="" ..="">text</name>
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Don't  get any errors neither any output. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
OK. I changed foreach($xml->name as $name)

to foreach($xml->lesson->name as $name)

so I get the values of the attribute. But now I don't know how to get the value of the children.
I've tried this:  $xml->lesson->children()

It prints children()

SOLVED: $text = $xml->lesson->children();
echo $text;

PROBLEM WAS: I'm using utf-8 in my other code but didn't change it.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I think this is one of those questions that is legitimately implied.  Short code sample, it doesn't output anything, what's wrong?

Comment: Probably because `$xml` refers to `<lessons>`, not `<lesson>`?

Comment: Might be so, and a solution would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** : this part related to a question typo.  <strike>If you copied your xml directly from where you were editting it, then part of the problem might be that it is malformed.  You have an opening `<lessons>` but you appear to wrongly try to close it with `</lesson>`.</strike>

Also, depending on your root node settings, `->name` may or may not be a child of the $xml object.  Can you post a `var_dump()` of it and get some clues?

Comment: I'm sorry it's being closed with </lessons> Just I who wrote it wrong here.

Comment: @Kilise how about that `var_dump()`?  :)

Comment: Solved it. It should be:  foreach($xml->lesson->name as $name)

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is some problem in your xml.

-> You have to close lessons tag correctly.Because  you have entered `</lesson>` (see last line) instead of `</lessons>`. If you start any tag, you should use the same tag name  while closing..

you can use this code to extract values from your xml,

```
<?php

$xmlstring='<lessons>
    <lesson level="1" course="2">
                 <name type="Dog" category="Animals">Dog name</name>
          </lesson>
</lessons>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$ATTRIBUTE=array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($xml->children() as $key=>$child)
  {
    $counter++;
    $ATTRIBUTE[$counter]["type"]=$child->name->attributes()->type;
    $ATTRIBUTE[$counter]["category"]=$child->name->attributes()->category;
    $ATTRIBUTE[$counter]["value"]= $child->name;
  }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ATTRIBUTE);
?>
```

here you will get everything in array. So you can fetch based on your requirement.